# .NET - Projection and dynamic return type don't match?

Tags: c#, .net

So I have this method:

```
public async Task<List<dynamic>> GetIdsOfPersoane()
    {
        return await GetRecords(true).Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Nume}).ToListAsync();
    }
```

GetRecords retrieves some data from the database.

Basically, I want to use projection but I don't want to create a new object only for this method. So I've done my research and I should return dynamic. I think this would work with object for sure, but I want to avoid boxing and unboxing.

The problem is that I get an error.

```
Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<{int Id, string Nume}>' to return type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't dynamic work this way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use generics or object?

Comment: @hunter object - still didn't work, and I wouldn't use it because of boxing and unboxing. Generics - I don't know how in this context.

Comment: What is the downside of creating a class that has `Id` and `Name`?

Comment: @hunter I don't think there is any to be honest. At first, I thought "let's try not to create one more class just for a method". Then I created it anyway, and now I'm left wondering how could this work without this extra class, just for learning purposes :)

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes. GetRecords() is a method which retrieves data from the database using EF.

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you'd want to call a method that selects into a known `anonymous` object but returns `dynamic`

I think you could eliminate this method entirely and call `GetRecords()` from whatever you're calling `GetIdsOfPersoane()` and select your anonymous object there

Comment: If you don't want to create your own type, you could re-use something like `KeyValuePair<int,string>`, or use tuples. I think `dynamic` is really a last resort.

Comment: why not use tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to make this compilable - provide generic type parameter for `ToListAsync`:

```cs
async Task<List<dynamic>> GetIdsOfPersoane()
{
    return await GetRecords(true)
        .Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Nume})
        .ToListAsync<dynamic>();
}
```

Or

```cs
async Task<List<dynamic>> GetIdsOfPersoane()
{
    return await GetRecords(true)
        .Select(p => new {p.Id, p.Nume})
        .ToListAsync<object>();
}
```

What you better do - create a type to return (with records it can be done very easy):

```cs
record PersonIdNume(int Id, string Nume);
async Task<List<PersonIdNume>> GetIdsOfPersoane()
{
    return await GetRecords(true)
       .Select(p => new PersonIdNume(p.Id, p.Nume))
       .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting concerns around strong-typing the return type aside in the public method. You can get around this via `ExpandoObject`.

```cs
return (await GetRecords(true)).Select(p =>
{
  dynamic result = new ExpandoObject();  // returns dynamic type
  result.Id = p.Id;
  result.Nume = p.Nume;

  return result;
})
```

Comment: Good answer. I chose the other one though because it had multiple ways, sorry :)